# CakePHP 4 - for 2 foreign keys in Table A, get corresponding data from Table B

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Using CakePHP 4.1.6

I have two tables in my database called `Categories` and `CategoryChanges`. The `Categories` table is simple in that it contains a list with ID's and names of several categories, e.g.

```
id | name
------------
1  | Foo
------------
2  | Bar
------------
3  | Baz
------------
```

My other table, `CategoryChanges`, is a log of when categories (as in `Categories`) in the application have been changed, as well as some other data such as who changed them and when.

In `CategoryChanges` there are two columns `category_id_from` and `category_id_to` which correspond to `Categories.id`.

So as an example `CategoryChanges` may include the following:

```
id | category_id_from | category_id_to | created    | user | notes 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
80 | 2                | 3              | 2021-02-03 | John | abcdef
--------------------------------------------------------------------
81 | 3                | 3              | 2021-03-15 | Jack | ghi
--------------------------------------------------------------------
82 | 1                | 2              | 2021-03-18 | Dave | zzz
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is output a table on a webpage which shows the above information but instead of having `category_id_from` and `category_id_to` as the numerical ID, I want `Categories.name` to appear. Note that it is also possible for some rows that the "from" and "to" values are the same (as an example see `CategoryChanges.id = 81`).

So the output I want would be this:

```
id | category_from | category_to | created    | user | notes 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
80 | Bar           | Baz         | 2021-02-03 | John | abcdef
--------------------------------------------------------------------
81 | Baz           | Baz         | 2021-03-15 | Jack | ghi
--------------------------------------------------------------------
82 | Foo           | Bar         | 2021-03-18 | Dave | zzz
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After reading the [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html) docs I can't see how to do this.

My assumption is that I need to read from the `CategoryChanges` table which is straightforward:

```
// in a Controller method
$CategoryChanges = $this->getTableLocator->get('CategoryChanges');
$query = $CategoryChanges->find();
```

If I execute `$query->toArray()` I would get the second table above, which contains the numerical ID's for `category_id_from` and `category_id_to`.

I assume that `$query` needs additional conditions - or possibly virtual fields - for "category from" and "category to". I can't see how to join these two columns to `Categories` such that I can get `Categories.name` as per table 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example simply add two `belongsTo` associations for those fields to your `CategoryChanges` table, and then comfortably use `innerJoinWith()` with your query, like:

```php
$this
    ->belongsTo('CategoryFrom')
    ->setClassName('Categories')
    ->setForeignKey('category_id_from');
    
$this
    ->belongsTo('CategoryTo')
    ->setClassName('Categories')
    ->setForeignKey('category_id_to');
```

```php
$query = $CategoryChanges
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'category_from' => 'CategoryFrom.name',
        'category_to' => 'CategoryTo.name',
        'created',
        'user',
        'notes',
    ])
    ->innerJoinWith('CategoryFrom')
    ->innerJoinWith('CategoryTo');
```